# Alignment of button inside table

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, html-table

My page looks like:

[image]

I would like to move the 'Save' button the the right of the text area, as opposed to underneath.

```
<th style="width:300px; text-align:center;">    
    <div style="position:relative; width:10px;">                       
       <textarea id="Utility" class='<%# GetIdOfCommentBox((int)Eval("id")) %>'
                 type="text" runat="server" rows="5" maxlength="200" />
       <input id="SubmitComments" type="button" value="Save"
              onclick="SubmitButton()"
              style="background-color:#EBEBFF; font-family:'Tahoma'; padding-left:3.8em; padding-right:3.8em; padding-top:0.3em; padding-bottom:0.3em" /> 
    </div>
</th>
```

Comment: float:right should work

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
style="float: right"
```

But in order to use this, you'll need to change container div `width` (10px) to something bigger

Comment: When i try float: right, it actually moves the button to the left. float:left then leaves it back to its original position?

Comment: ah yes changing the size of the div resolved this thanks Claudio

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some kind of .css?

If you are using it:

```
.SubmitComments{
margin-right:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style='float:right;width:100%'><input id="SubmitComments" type="button" value="Save" ... /></div>
<div style='clear:both'></div>
```